# Windows Task Scheduler Hangs When Python Script Fails

Tags: windows, python, scheduled-tasks

I have a python script that is being called via Task Scheduler. When the script fails, I'd like it to retry the task. I have set the "If the task fails, restart every X minutes" on settings.

In addition, I have the task set up to repeat every X minutes on the Triggers page. I do not want more than one instance running (since it writes to a database).

However, when the script fails, it seems to be hanging the window and keeping it open. This results in the restart not happening, nor the next triggering. Any advice on how to make it fail harder and close the batch file window?

Comment: There is a lot here to look at. What is a script "failure"? How are you calling the script? Is there database activity during the time the scheduler hangs?
It sounds like this would be better off on a more specific programming area of Stack Exchange

Comment: Script is called via a batch file that calls "python [script loc]". Failures is an error code returned by the module in python. The code works most of the time, but sometimes it times out. When it does, the python throws an error and the batch window from Task Scheduler stays open - seemingly not recognizing the error.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.